# Checking if an IP address is in multiple possible subnets

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, ip

I am parsing Apache logs and would like to check whether an IP address belongs in a list of ~300 possible subnets (https://github.com/client9/ipcat).

- There are many different IPs from Internet traffic (I don't know what subnet they belong to).
- I'm using the Apache Commons SubnetUtils package to store the subnets.
- Storing all possible IP's in a hashmap from the 300 subnets takes too much memory.
- Iterating through each SubnetUtil for each IP (even with a HashMap cache for previous lookups) is very slow.

Is there something else I can be doing here?

Comment: You can build a tree structure with subnets - it can be bit by bit. That would reduce the checks from 300 to a maximum of 32 (assuming IPv4) but likely much less in most cases.

Comment: You can use Guava's [`RangeSet`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#rangeset) to hold IP ranges as longs or integers (mind the overflow).

Answer (score 1):

You can build a tree structure with subnets - it can be bit by bit. That would reduce the checks from 300 to a maximum of 32 (assuming IPv4) but much less in most cases. (Because it either doesn't match after a few bits, or it matches at the average length of the subnet netmasks)

Here's a simple binary tree implementation that does this. You'll probably want to decorate it with some functions to parse subnets in their more usual `"a.b.c.d/e"` format.

```
public class SubnetTree {
    private SubnetTree one, zero;
    private boolean terminating;

    public void addSubnet(int net, int bits) {
        if (terminating) {
            // If this node is already terminating, then no need to add
            // subnets that are more specific
            return;
        }
        if (bits > 0) {
            boolean bit = ((net >>> 31) & 1) == 1;
            if (bit) {
                if (one == null) {
                    one = new SubnetTree();
                }
                one.addSubnet(net << 1, bits - 1);
            } else {
                if (zero == null) {
                    zero = new SubnetTree();
                }
                zero.addSubnet(net << 1, bits - 1);
            }
        } else {
            terminating = true;
        }
    }

    public boolean isInRange(int address) {
        if (terminating) {
            return true;
        }
        boolean bit = ((address >>> 31) & 1) == 1;
        if (bit) {
            if (one == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return one.isInRange(address << 1);
            }
        } else {
            if (zero == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return zero.isInRange(address << 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A very simple test for this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubnetTree tree = new SubnetTree();
    tree.add(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("01100110000000000000000000000000", 2), 8);
    System.out.println("true: " + tree.isInRange(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("01100110000000000000100010000101", 2)));
    System.out.println("false: " + tree.isInRange(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("01101110000000000000100010000101", 2)));

    tree.add(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("01001110000000000000000000000000", 2), 6);
    System.out.println("true: " + tree.isInRange(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("01100110000000000000100010000101", 2)));
    System.out.println("false: " + tree.isInRange(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("01101110000000000000100010000101", 2)));
    System.out.println("true: " + tree.isInRange(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("01001110100000000000000000000000", 2)));
    System.out.println("true: " + tree.isInRange(Integer.parseUnsignedInt("01001100100000000000000000111111", 2)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Will have a play with it

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to build a Trie (Tree of prefixes) for all you subnets. The search in it will be very fast, with a worst case the length of your longest subnet prefix (ultimately 32). Memory wise it is pretty efficient too.

Think of your subnets in binary representations, and thus the tree will store that. IPs addresses should then be converted to binary as well, and the tree used for search. When reaching a leaf, you check if it's a valid subnet.

Here is a quite complete implementation / example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CheckIpAdrBelongsToSubnet {
  private static final String [] CIDR_SUBNETS = {"192.5.0.0/16", "10.10.0.0/16"};

  public static void main(String ... ips) {
    BinaryTrieNode root = createBinaryTrieFromCidrs(CIDR_SUBNETS);

    for(String ip :ips) {
      System.out.println(ip + " belongs to a subnet in list: " + ipBelongsToCidrs(ip, root));
    }
  }

  static boolean ipBelongsToCidrs(String ipv4, BinaryTrieNode root) {
    BinaryIpV4 bipv4 = new BinaryIpV4(ipv4);
    BinaryTrieNode current = root;
    for(boolean b : bipv4.getBinIp()) {
      BinaryTrieNode nextCurr = current.getNode(b);
      if(nextCurr == null) {
        return current.isEndOfValidPrefix();
      } else {
        current = nextCurr;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  static BinaryTrieNode createBinaryTrieFromCidrs(String [] cidrs) {
    BinaryTrieNode root = new BinaryTrieNode();

    for (String cidr : cidrs) {
      String ipv4 = cidr.split("/")[0];
      int prefixLength = Integer.parseInt(cidr.split("/")[1]);
      BinaryIpV4 bipv4 = new BinaryIpV4(ipv4, prefixLength);

      BinaryTrieNode current = root;
      for(boolean b : bipv4.getBinIp()) {
        BinaryTrieNode nextCurr = current.getNode(b);
        if(nextCurr == null) {
          nextCurr = new BinaryTrieNode();
          current.setNode(b, nextCurr);
        }
        current = nextCurr;
      }
      current.setEndOfValidPrefix(true);
    }

    return root;
  }

  public static class BinaryIpV4 {
    boolean [] binIp;

    BinaryIpV4(String ipv4) {
      translateCidrToBinPrefix(ipv4,32);
    }

    BinaryIpV4(String ipv4, int prefixLength) {
      translateCidrToBinPrefix(ipv4,prefixLength);
    }

    void translateCidrToBinPrefix(String ipv4, int prefixLength) {
      String [] bytes = ipv4.split("\\.");
      binIp = new boolean [prefixLength];
      int idx = 0;

      for(String b : bytes) {
        int by = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(b);
        String binByte = getBinaryString(by);

        for(int i = 0; i < binByte.length() ; i++) {
          binIp[idx++] = binByte.charAt(i)=='1';

          if(idx >= prefixLength) {
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    public boolean[] getBinIp() {
      return binIp;
    }

    String getBinaryString(int b) {
      return String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
    }

    public String toString() {
      return Arrays.toString(binIp);
    }
  }

  public static class BinaryTrieNode {
    private boolean isEndOfValidPrefix=false;

    private BinaryTrieNode zeroNode;
    private BinaryTrieNode oneNode;

    public boolean isEndOfValidPrefix() {
      return isEndOfValidPrefix;
    }
    public void setEndOfValidPrefix(boolean isEndOfValidPrefix) {
      this.isEndOfValidPrefix = isEndOfValidPrefix;
    }
    public BinaryTrieNode getNode(boolean b) {
      return b?oneNode:zeroNode;
    }
    public void setNode(boolean b, BinaryTrieNode node) {
      if(b) {
        this.oneNode = node;
      } else {
        this.zeroNode = node;
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd do:

- Set a policy in advance that no subnet may overlap with any other subnet.
- Sort the subnets in ascending order by starting IP (once).
- For each IP, perform a binary search of the array, returning the last IP smaller than or equal to the IP.
- Check that one subnet.

After the initial conversion of the IP strings to integers, this is O(log2(n)) simple numerical comparisons where n is 300 (so about 9) plus a single bitwise AND and one additional numerical comparison.

To convert the string to an integer in C, you'd do this:

```
struct in_addr addr;
int ip = inet_aton(stringAddress, &addr);
```

for each IP (both the subnets and the ones you're checking).  And for the mask:

```
uint32_t mask_val = ~((1 << (32 - nbits)) - 1);
// e.g. a mask of 30 gives you ~[[1 << 2 == 0b100] - 1 = 0b11] = 0b111...100
```

I assume most other languages have similar features.

Then you would compare them with:

```
if (ip & mask == subnet) { // match }
```

Comment: There are already two older answers that describe a solution in time complexity O(1) and in Java.

Comment: No, they aren't O(1).  They are O(k) where k is the number of bits.  And that ends up being considerably slower than what I described.

Comment: No they're O(1) - O(32) equals O(1) - we only call something O(n) when they're is no fixed upper limit.

Comment: You're missing my point, which is that the constant is so large that even if we assume you won't ever see a subnet smaller than /28, the seemingly more complex O(log2(n)) algorithm is likely to take less time until you have several hundred million subnets to compare.